# When a database locks the data?

Tags: sql

I just want to have this clear. I know that when a Session A tries to update a cell that is currently in use by Session B, the database lock that data and Session A have to wait for Session B to finish.

This can happen with SQL Statements like UPDATE, but, what happens if Session B are performing a SELECT

Does Session A have to wait too ?

Comment: Depends on your [tag:rdbms], at the very least

Comment: You appear to be using words that are not normally associated with SQL.  What is a "session," what is a "cell," and what do you consider "data?"  The whole database?

Answer (score 0):

No locking is needed if the only transactions on the database are `SELECT`s.

Locking is needed to "protect" rows when data is being changed.  They are not needed when data is only being read.  So, if one of the sessions is doing a data modification (such as an `UPDATE`), then it could block a `SELECT`.

As a note:  databases have no concept of "cells".  Locks (depending on the database) are available on the table, page, and row levels.

I should point out that this is for "standard" database technology.  Column-oriented databases operate a bit differently.

Comment: That would be implementation dependent. There are definitely databases that blocks SELECTs when changes are done in another session. So, very db specific.

Comment: I would not be shocked if the concepts of rows and columns in a relational database are sometimes conflated with rows and columns in a spreadsheet, and that therefore people sometimes confuse "fields" and "cells". ALthough there's still no locking at the "field" level either. :-)

Answer (score 0):

"if Session B are performing a SELECT" - depends on the isolation level of the session B.
If "repeatable read" and no MVCC-DBMS or "serializable" then a record read in session B must be locked against changes, otherwise the condition of a second identical read can not be met.